# Nodejs - difference between spawn.stdout and process.stdout

Tags: node.js, child-process

Playing around with child_process and I want to pipe spawned cp output to custom stream.

I don't understand why in first case piping doesn't works and in second does.

#### Presets

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const process = require('process');
const stream = require('stream');

var writable = new stream.Writable();
writable._write = function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
};
```

#### Doesn't work

```
var spawnedProcess = cp.spawn('ls', [], {
    stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr] 
});
process.stdout.pipe(writable);
```

Outputs log into terminal but does't pipe it.

#### Does work

```
var spawnedProcess = cp.spawn('ls', [], {});
spawnedProcess.stdout.pipe(writable);
```

Pipes output to `writable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc says [`process.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) is only a Writable stream so you can't pipe from it. It's weird it doesn't throw an `Error: Cannot pipe. Not readable.` though. Also, [`cp.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout) is a Readable stream so it pipes as it should.

Comment: Understood. Bit off topic, if I would like to put custom stdout for spawn, it should be readable stream then?
I'll be free to share my related question with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967278/nodejs-child-process-spawn-custom-stdio

Comment: @MrBr Nope, when you pipe to a stream, that destination stream has to be Writable: `readable.pipe(writable);`. I answered your other question :)