# Node.js execSync redirect stderr to stdout

Tags: node.js, stdout, child-process, stderr

I'm trying to redirect the subprocess stderr to it's stdout with:

```js
let buffer = execSync("echo hello 1>&2", {stdio : ["pipe","pipe", 1]});
console.log("Result: " + buffer.toString());
```

My goal is to retrieve "hello" inside my variable "buffer".
In the documentation I see that it's possible to redirect the stderr: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

So I tried at first to just pipe the stderr to the stdout (see code above) but I figured out that it redirect to the parent process stdout.

Resulting in the following output:

```
node .\main.js
hello
Result:
```

I tried to add a custom Buffer:

```js
const {subprocess, execSync} = require("node:child_process");
let buff = Buffer.alloc(128);

execSync("echo hello 1>&2", {stdio : ["pipe",buff, buff]});
console.log("Result:" + buff.toString());
```

But the buffer stays empty:

```
node .\main.js
Result:
```

Is it possible to redirect the subprocess stderr to the subprocess stdout returned by `execSync` ? Or am I mandatory to use [custom stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35014260/12519438) or [`spawnSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawnsynccommand-args-options) ?

Answer (score 0):

[`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options) returns the stdout of the executed command, irrespective of the `stdio` option. What you want to achieve can be done with the asynchronous [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback):

```js
child_process.exec("echo hello 1>&2", function(error, stdout, buffer){
  console.log("Result: " + buffer.toString());
});
```

Comment: Ok so there is definitely no option to do so with the synchronous method ?

Comment: is there a way to merge the stdout and stderr ? @Heiko